Permissions for CREATE DATABASE AS COPY OF
I have two databases in an Azure SQL Database elastic pool "MyPool" named db1 and db2.
I want to copy db1 to a new database, db3.
I should be able to do this with:
CREATE DATABASE db3 AS COPY OF db1 (SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ELASTIC_POOL(name = MyPool))

I connect to the database server with SSMS using the SQL Login "dbuser".
When I run this using SSMS, connected to "master", I get:

Insufficient permission to create a database copy on server 'mydbserver'. Ensure that the user login 'dbuser' has the correct permissions on the source and target servers.

According to the docs, I should just have to add "dbuser" to the role "dbmanager"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-copy?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#copy-using-transact-sql
It says: "For database copy to succeed, logins that aren't the server administrator must be members of the dbmanager role."
So in "master" I run:
ALTER ROLE dbmanager ADD MEMBER dbuser

That runs successfully. (I also tried this in db1 but the role dbmanager does not exist.)
But the CREATE DATABASE... AS COPY OF... still gives the above error.
I am able to do just:
CREATE DATABASE db3

and it will create an empty database. But adding the "AS COPY OF" fails.
I have also tried leaving off the clause that adds it to the pool - same error.
I have tried adding "dbuser" to the "db_owner" role on db1. Same error.
What does it need to get this to work?

I think you are not taking in consideration the permissions needed to manage an Elastic Pool. One thing is the permissions needed to perform a copy of an Azure SQL Database and the other thing is the permissions needed to add a database to an Azure Elastic Pool. To add a database to an elastic pool you may need the Contributor role assignment on the IAM Access Control on the Azure Portal.
For example, the following should work to just copy the database without adding the copy database to the pool.
-- Connect to source server master database using Server Admin credentials
CREATE LOGIN copyUser WITH PASSWORD = '{PutStrongPassword}';
CREATE USER copyUser FROM LOGIN copyUser;
 
-- connect to source database using Server Admin credentials
CREATE USER copyUser FROM LOGIN copyUser;
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER copyUser;
 
-- Connect to destination server master database using Server Admin credentials
CREATE LOGIN copyUser WITH PASSWORD = '{PutStrongPassword}';
CREATE USER copyUser FROM LOGIN copyUser;
ALTER ROLE dbmanager ADD MEMBER copyUser;
 
-- Connect to destination server master database using copyUser
CREATE DATABASE testcopy AS COPY OF mysource.mydb1 (EDITION = 'Standard', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S1');


None of these helped. I created a new login/user, gave that user the db owner role in the two databases. There is no destination server - the copy is being done on the same server. I am able to create a database (empty) as the new user, either inside the pool or outside. Per the SQL docs, I also tried adding the user to the roles ##MS_DatabaseManager##, ##MS_LoginManager##, and ##MS_DatabaseConnector##. None of it worked. I was only able to get it to work by using the SQL Admin Account (equivalent of "sa" when the Azure SQL Server is set up). I'd prefer to not use that login, but it works.
